Gaps on either side of my dishwasher
My apartment is the ground level of a three level house. It was made in a makeshift way into these three apartments. Done very poorly. My dishwasher broke a little over a year ago and when they took out the old one. It seems the kitchen wall under the counter where the dishwasher was ends halfway back and you can see the unfinished foundation and just rocks and dirt.
Well last fall, because I'm in an urban area, there was a rat.
This rat got into my kitchen. My cat was out there and I heard a weird sound and when I went out in the little bit of light I saw the rats behind running the direction of the dishwasher. I imagine it got in from along the side of it because of the gaps between the dishwasher and the wall or the counter on either side.
Is there anything I can get that's safe to put in these gaps to discourage rodents from getting in there? I mentioned to my landlord about the gap and they said they don't wanna close off the wall because the dishwasher will have to be unhooked etc. so is there anything I can get to fill in the gaps on either side of it so a rat wouldn't have a way in without chewing it's way in at least? It just feels like an open door invitation and I'd like to do something about it before the fall.

what about the cat

Unhooking the dishwasher should take as long as it did hooking it up.  So not really a good excuse.  About the only thing that stops rats is metal, either heavy duty fine screen or thin(but thicker than foil) plate.  Almost anything else(except cement) just slows them down.

This is a health issue since rats carry a plethora of diseases.  Unhooking the dishwasher should only take minutes.  It is a weak excuse, considering the health department could demand a fix along with many more if the apartment was to be inspected.  I'm betting it was not even permitted and the authorities could condemn the entire building. Your landlord has a lot to loose by not correcting this situation.

Are you able to add a photo of the space?

@Traveler, right, how about a cat upgrade?
